# Extract data from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, minimum

I have the following list:

```
[N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.572034
 relative std     0.284350
 dtype: float64,
 N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.571815
 relative std     0.284262
 dtype: float64,
 N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.572101
 relative std     0.284412
 dtype: float64,
 N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.572115
 relative std     0.284440
 dtype: float64,
 N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.571872
 relative std     0.284313
 dtype: float64]
```

I would like to extract the data (N, mean, std, relative std) from the list which has the minimum relative std value. The output of the above list should be the following:

```
 N               12.000000
 mean             2.011608
 median           2.021611
 std              0.571815
 relative std     0.284262
 dtype: float64
```

What I tried so far?

```
min(list)
```

But the throws the following error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: Can you share your list in a more copy/paste friendly way? Is that a list of dataframes?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min` with lambda function for select values of `Series` by label `std`:

```
s1 = pd.Series([0,1,2], index=['std','min','max'])
s2 = pd.Series([4,1,2], index=['std','min','max'])
s3 = pd.Series([0.8,1,2], index=['std','min','max'])

L = [s1, s2, s3]

s = min(L, key=lambda x:x.loc['std'])
print (s)
std    0
min    1
max    2
dtype: int64
```

For test all minimals:

```
print ([x.loc['std'] for x in L])
[0, 4, 0.8]
```

And for index use `np.argmin`:

```
import numpy as np
print (np.argmin([x.loc['std'] for x in L]))
0
```

Comment: @MuSu18 - in need minimal value `min(x.loc['std'] for x in lst)`

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to extract the index of the minimum value?

Comment: I tried L.index(min(L, key=lambda x:x.loc['std'])) it gives me an error saying 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().'

Comment: @MuSu18 - What is `type(L[0])` ?

Comment: The type is pandas.core.series.Series

Comment: @MuSu18 - In list are all Series?

Comment: Yes, all are series

Comment: @MuSu18 - So what is `[x.loc['std'] for x in lst]` ?

Comment: It lists out all the values of std. The output looks like the following ```[0.5717808890503777,
 0.5721950145669352,
 0.5721768182360689,
 0.5720823409032569,
 0.5721597650972318]```

Comment: @MuSu18 - Super, then use `np.argmin([x.loc['std'] for x in L])`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yo are the best. I also tried ```(min(L, key=lambda x:x.loc['std'])).argmax()``` That works as well..